# Splitting string from variable in php

Tags: php, string, split

I currently have a problem regarding splitting strings stored in a variable in PHP.

I have a website and a php script that takes a string (4-6 words e.g. The University of Reading) from a database field, store it in a variable and displays it on the screen. It loops around the database and outputs many different strings.

The strings contain names of universities, e.g. Brunel University, University of Reading etc. 
The php script displays the names of the universities in alphabetical order. Obviously it reads 'University of...' first, therefore sorts many universities in the wrong order.

e.g. the list:

```
Brunel University
University of Reading
University of Birmingham
Cardiff University 
University of Essex
```

is currently sorted like:

```
Brunel University
Cardiff University
University of Birmingham
University of Essex
University of Reading
```

whereas it should be sorted like:

```
Birmingham, University of 
Brunel University
Cardiff University 
Essex, University of 
Reading, University of
```

I need to search through each string before it is displayed to check whether it contains the words 'University of', if it does, I need to remove these words and put them at the end of the string. I then need to display the string.

I hope this makes sense, if anyone could advise me on how to do this I would appreciate it.

EDIT

The code I'm using is below. I figured I may need to use the 'explode' function somewhere?

```
<tr>
<td><table class="flat-table flat-table-2" width="100%">
<tr>
</tr>

<tr style="background-color:#FFF;">
<td class="table-head">Name</td>
<td class="table-head">Average Hall Rating</td>
</tr>

<?php
//run a query to find all the fields in the hall table that belong to the specific     university, using the id in the url ($current_id)
if ($s = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM university ORDER BY name ASC")) { 
    $s->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.

    //search table for all fields and save them in $hall
    $unitemp = $s->fetchAll();
    foreach( $unitemp as $uni) {

    //store each halls id
    $uni_id = "university.php?id=$uni[id]";

    //loop and output hall names below
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $uni['name'];?></td>
<td><? echo $uni['rating']; }}?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you show us some of the code that you've already worked on?

Comment: I have just edited the post, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are stuck at, but here is how you can find if "University of" is in a string (taken from the php manual): 

$findme = "University of";
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated some lines in the code:

```
     <?php
     //run a query to find all the fields in the hall table that belong to the specific        university, using the id in the url ($current_id)
     if ($s = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM university ORDER BY name ASC")) { 
         $s->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.

         //search table for all fields and save them in $hall
         $unitemp = $s->fetchAll();
         foreach( $unitemp as $uni) {

             $pieces = explode("of", $uni['name']);

             if(count($pieces)>1)
                 $response = $pieces[1].", ".$pieces[1]." of";
             else
                 $response = $pieces[0]; 

             echo $response;

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Glancing at this, it seems like you want to create an updated list, where the University names are listed as `Reading, University` for Universities that start with `University`. You would need to loop through your list, generating a new one that does this.

```
$universities = $UNIVERSITY_LIST_HERE
$uniNames[];
foreach ($unversities as $uni){
    $uniStr = substr($uni, 0, 12);
    if($uniStr == "University of"){
        // split the string
        $uniNames[] = substr($uni, 13) . ', ' . $uniStr;
    } else {
        $uniNames[] = $uni;
    }
}
```

You can then pass the `$uniNames` into your sort algorithm. PHP has a nice `sort();` algorithm that you can use. Below, I'm printing out the names inside the foreach loop.

```
sort($uniNames);
foreach ($uniNames as $key => $val) {
    echo "uniNames[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
```

Comment: There isn't a list and there isn't a sort algorithm. The php script uses - $s = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM university ORDER BY name ASC" - to sort the list alphabetically

Comment: You would need to either store it in the `Reading, University of` format into the database, or you'll have to create a sorting algorithm to use after. If you'd like me to add a sorting algorithm into my above code, I can

Comment: It would be great if you could include the sort algorithm @aashnisshah

Comment: there's a nice easy `sort()` function in PHP. I updated the code above.

Comment: thank you very much. the line - $universities = $UNIVERSITY_LIST_HERE - how would I get around that, as there isn't actually a list of universities that I am using. Just data in a databse @aashnisshah

Comment: thank you very much for this code, but I've decided to use code provided below.